# Typing RxJs fromEvent's parameter as a MouseEvent yields error

Tags: angular, rxjs, mouseevent

I'm trying to listen to a user's mouse click on a DOM element, and to fetch the event's clientX/clientY mouse coordinates. Using angular v12.1.5 and RxJs v6.6.0.

```js
const click$ = () =>
fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(
  map((ev: MouseEvent) => ev.clientX)
)
```

The code above yields the following error:

```
Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<MouseEvent, number>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Event, number>'.
  Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 21 more.ts(2345)
```

I copy pasted the code above from the [RxJs documentation for map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map), so I'm confused as to why this doesn't work. Is it a version issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the `fromEvent` function returns an object of type `Event`, while `ev` is supposed to by of type `MouseEvent`. One way of achieving the desired behavior would be to do something like:

```
const click$ = fromEvent(window, 'click').pipe(
    map((event: Event) => event as MouseEvent),
    map((mouseEvent: MouseEvent) => mouseEvent.clientX)
);
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm still new to both typescript and RxJS and didn't realize one could typecast in a map pipe the way you did. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you import Event and MouseEvent? @JohnC

Comment: Hm I'm not importing those anywhere in my code explicitly @CelalettinTurgut -- MouseEvent is a 'default' typescript type as far as I know, and I think Event here is an RxJS type. I could be wrong about those types though.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works the same way as @Jan Schumann stated. We just don't have to map Event to MouseEvent.

```
const click$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(window, 'click').pipe(
   map((mouseEvent) => mouseEvent.clientX)
);
```